# Odoo module Journal Entry

Tags: python, odoo

what my code does:
1.- Reads the lines of an excel file.
2.- Assigns each row to its corresponding field.
3.-and proceeds to store each row in the database, one at a time.
the error that I get when I run it is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USduY.png)

```
import json
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from odoo import models, fields, api
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

class AccountMoveInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.move'


    def importar_action(self):

        # Cargar el archivo de Excel sin espacios en el nombre.
        ruta_modulo = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        archivo_ruta = os.path.join(ruta_modulo, 'static', 'src', 'lineasdefacturas5.xlsx')

        
        # workbook = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\pimog\Desktop\TRABAJO PRACTICAS\TAREAS\migracion de continental a odoo\excel de importacion\facturas\lineasdefacturas5.xlsx')
        workbook = load_workbook(archivo_ruta)

        # Seleccionar la hoja de origen
        ws_origen = workbook['Query1']

        #obtenemos la longitud de las filas y columnas
        filas_origen = ws_origen.max_row
       # columnas_origen = ws_origen.max_column
        columnas_origen = 8
    
        for fila in range(2, filas_origen + 1):
            lista_valores = [None] * 8
            numero = 0
            for columna in range(1, columnas_origen + 1):
                valor_celda = ws_origen.cell(row=fila, column=columna).value
                lista_valores[numero] = valor_celda
                numero += 1

                idFact = self.env['ir.model.data'].search([('name','=',lista_valores[1])]).res_id
                idProduct = self.env['product.template'].search([('name','=',lista_valores[2])]).id
                #consultar idexterno y otras tablas
                #self.env['product.product'].search([('name','=','Orden_de_reparacion')]).id
                
            objeto = {
                'id': lista_valores[0],
                'move_id': idFact,
                'product_id': idProduct,
                'quantity': lista_valores[3],
                'price_unit': lista_valores[4],
                'company_currency_id': lista_valores[5],
                'journal_id': lista_valores[6],
                'account_id': lista_valores[7],
                }
            record = self.env['account.move.line'].create(objeto)
        # raise ValidationError(fila)
```

I am not sure which variable I am missing.

Comment: ***DO NOT*** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word **traceback**. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output

Comment: `'move_id': idFact` could be a falsy value, which leads to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check for mandatory fields and sets their values before creating the records:

```py
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from odoo import models, fields, api
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

class AccountMoveInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.move'

    def importar_action(self):
        ruta_modulo = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        archivo_ruta = os.path.join(ruta_modulo, 'static', 'src', 'lineasdefacturas5.xlsx')
        workbook = load_workbook(archivo_ruta)
        ws_origen = workbook['Query1']
        filas_origen = ws_origen.max_row
        columnas_origen = 8

        for fila in range(2, filas_origen + 1):
            lista_valores = [None] * 8
            numero = 0
            for columna in range(1, columnas_origen + 1):
                valor_celda = ws_origen.cell(row=fila, column=columna).value
                lista_valores[numero] = valor_celda
                numero += 1

            idFact = self.env['ir.model.data'].search([('name', '=', lista_valores[1])]).res_id
            idProduct = self.env['product.template'].search([('name', '=', lista_valores[2])], limit=1).id

            objeto = {
                'move_id': idFact,
                'product_id': idProduct,
                'quantity': lista_valores[3],
                'price_unit': lista_valores[4],
                'company_currency_id': lista_valores[5],
                'journal_id': lista_valores[6],
                'account_id': lista_valores[7],
            }

            # Check for mandatory fields and set their values
            mandatory_fields = self.env['account.move.line'].fields_get().keys()
            missing_fields = set(mandatory_fields) - set(objeto.keys())
            if missing_fields:
                raise ValidationError(f"Missing mandatory fields: {missing_fields}")

            record = self.env['account.move.line'].create(objeto)
```